# Changing UIButton alpha then doesn't recognize tap

Tags: swift, uibutton

I set up an interface very much like youtube in the sense that if a user presses on a UIView, I'll hide or show all of the subviews with an animation.

```
func setupControlViewVisiblity(playingVideo: Bool = false, duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, isExpanded: Bool = false){
        var alpha:CGFloat = 1

    if isShowingControls {
        //If we're showing then we're about to hide everything so alpha is 0
        alpha = 0
    }


    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.pausePlayButton.alpha = alpha
        self.backButton.alpha = alpha
        self.infoLabel.alpha = alpha
        self.fullScreenButton.alpha = alpha
        self.currentTimeLabel.alpha = alpha
        self.videoLengthLabel.alpha = alpha
        self.videoSlider.alpha = alpha

    }, completion:nil)

    isShowingControls = !isShowingControls
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that if I call this method and I show the controls (isShowingControls is true), my UIButtons will not recognize the first tap. This literally only happens when the views alpha go from 0 to 1 then I try to tap a button.

I tried doing the animation on the main queue... doesn't work. If I change the alpha from 0 to 1.... wait a few seconds... then tap the button.. it works. How can I make it work right after the UIButtons alpha changed?

Thanks

EDIT: I guess it has to do with the animation duration because when I switch it down to 0.2 it works. How can I keep it a bit higher and get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default UIVIew animations do not allow user interaction while the animation is animating.

Luckily there is an animation option `allowUserInteraction`. Not much more information but you can see it in documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/1622440-allowuserinteraction). Also worth checking out all the options [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions).

Try this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {

     // Update the views

}, completion:nil)
```